# Sass::SyntaxError in _base.scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, css

I'm getting a syntax error in my css file in rails.

File name: _base.scss

```
        body {
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: $grey;
        font-family: $body-font;
          }
```

Undefined variable: "$grey".
  (in /home/mali/rails_projects/platform-rails3/app/assets/stylesheets/_base.css.scss)

Any idea why this error comes up and how do I solve it? Thanks in advance.
Funny thing is it is working when I include it in view like application:

```
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

but not working like this:

```
           <%= stylesheet_link_tag "_base" %>
```

Comment: Let me guess, its `$gray` not `$grey`

Comment: Where have you defined it?

Comment: no where it is sass isnt it??

Comment: Does your application.css.scss include more stuff, like the definition of $grey maybe?

Comment: Yes it does the main.scss have its definition

Comment: So that's the problem; I'll make it my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Gray (with an a) is a css constant colour (#808080).
$grey is a sass variable which has to be defined to hold the colour before you use it.

```
@import 'main';
```

at the top of your _base.scss file.

You may want to consider extracting only the colour definitions out to their own scss file (which you @import into everything you need) if there is too much in main that you don't want to include in every sub scss file.

Comment: Thats the problem i have added this but it doesnt work it is working fine with: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>  but not with: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "_base" %>

Comment: Try dropping the underscore from the start of _base.scss  The underscore in sass means it's a partial file which will not be compiled into css.